# Python kernel crashes every time after opening editor

Tags: python

Until yesterday evening my python installation worked great.

Today I opened it and the kernel did not start. I tried everything.
I even reinstalled enthought canopy a few times on my windows7 32bit. I digged into the .../appdata/enthought/ folder and deleted the folder manually between two installs.

I tried to install "ipython" as the log suggests below. I deleted "Queue.py".
Any clues what to do next?

Log starts:

> > The kernel (user Python environment) has terminated with error code 1. This may be due to a bug in your code or in the kernel itself.
>
> If you were using a pre-Jupyter Canopy and have not already updated
>   the "ipython" package in the Canopy Package Manager, please do so now,
>   then restart the kernel.
>
> Otherwise, you may wish to view the output captured from the kernel
>   process, shown below:
>
> 10 20 30 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
>   29, in    File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\IPython\kernel__init__.py", line 4, in
>      File
>   "build\bdist.win32\egg\IPython\kernel\zmq__init__.py", line 16, in
>      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\IPython\kernel\zmq\session.py",
>   line 53, in    File
>   "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop__init__.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop   File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py",
>   line 35, in 
>       from tornado.ioloop import PollIOLoop, PeriodicCallback   File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py",
>   line 46, in 
>       from tornado.concurrent import TracebackFuture, is_future   File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py",
>   line 37, in 
>       from concurrent import futures   File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures__init__.py", line 17, in 
>       from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor   File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\thread.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       import Queue as queue   File "Queue.py", line 26, in 
>       def **init**(self, maxsize=0):   File "Queue.py", line 10, in remove
>        IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Uhh... if you have an issue with a library and the exception traces to the standard library, I would not under any circumstance recommend that the solution to that is to **delete the source file from the standard library**. Did I misunderstand what you did?

Comment: Queue.py is a file I created. I removed it from my workspace.

Comment: I don't get why the kernel wants to load it every time...

Comment: Ah I see. You accidentally shadowed [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) in the std lib. It's trying to open it every time because one of your libs (canopy, I guess) is trying to require it.

Comment: Yes, this can be the reason. How can I solve it? Re-installation hasn't worked.

Comment: Does it work when you remove or rename your `Queue.py`?

Comment: I removed it already and then I reinstalled python too. I'll run a search again...

Comment: @Lac: do you by chance still have a `Queue.pyc` (bytecode file) around after removing `Queue.py`? Also, remove `__pycache__` folders. It could be loading Queue from there.

Answer (score 0):

Before Canopy support answered, I found a way to write python code in **Eclipse IDE**. Simply download pydev.zip and unzip it into the *Eclipse_installation\dropins* folder. A python installation is prerequisite of course.

Pydev download: http://www.pydev.org/download.html

**Canopy support** answered the following:

> Please perform a Full Reset of Canopy by following the instructions in
>   this article:
>   https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy